# Spring Framework - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor

Tags: java, spring, jar

While I was trying to run a simple static pointcut example in Spring on Eclipse, I came across this error message :-

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class
>   net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor

Answer (score 5):

First, find out which cglib version is compatible with asm-3.1. Second, use only compatible version. Now you use 2 cglib jars of different versions (which is always bad).

Comment: +1, just to add on - the specific version of CGLIB compatible with Spring 3.1.2 is cglib 2.2.2 , asm 3.3.1, removing cglib-3.0 should just do it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a compatible version mentioned here, helped to resolve this issue.

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/exception-handling/solved-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class